# Why we can't declare whole class as synchronized in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronize

I am new to Java I just want to know what if whole class in Java will be synchronized, what will be the possible problems? I know the concept of class level locking, which is different.

Comment: I don't think `synchronized` is allowed at the class level, but it is certainly possible to create classes with are thread safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marking the whole class `synchronized` would be misleading. Although there are situations when it makes perfect sense to make all methods of a class `synchronized`, a class typically contains other declarations that cannot be `synchronized`.

For example, class constructor cannot be marked `synchronized`. Same goes for fields of a class. One could mistakingly assume that fields in a class marked `synchronized` would be accessed in a synchronized way, but that is not something that Java does automatically. Of course language designers could declare that `synchronized` on class level applies only to methods, but such decision would be somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: Another thing to consider is how a `synchronized` keyword at the class level should affect methods inherited from a superclass or methods overridden or just added by a subclass.

Comment: Also, would this make all `static` methods `synchronized` as well, or not?

Comment: Assume that Java is allowing to declare class as Synchronized, then how it is affecting to object creation of that class? I am just talking about main thread, how its behavior get affected when we declare class as synchronized?

Comment: @MayurGite The problem is that Java does not have a good alternative that would be universally applicable: object creation is something that operates on an instance, but is related to the class as a whole. It could behave like a `static` synchronized method, but then it would lock out other static methods. Generally, lack of such a good alternative is the reason why Java does not let you mark constructors `synchronized`.

Answer (score 0):

The `synchronized` keyword can only be used on method declarations and as `synchronized` blocks. When used on a method declaration, it's the same as adding a `synchronized` block around the contents of the method, synchronizing on `this`. There is nothing preventing you from synchronizing every method of a class. If you use `synchronized` keyword on every method declaration that would mean that only one method of the class can execute concurrently. In a multi-threaded application this could cause poor performance, but there isn't anything to prevent you doing it.